# Mixing ram, what can I add that wont cause trouble?

Tags: hardware, memory, latency

Hey I have some of [this](http://www.mushkin.com/Memory/Blackline/991601.aspx) this in a home server and wanted to throw another couple gigs in there. The problem is that its out of production, so I don't know what I can mix it with. I havent found anything sofar that matches CAS and voltage. [This](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820226103&cm_re=ddr3_1600_pc3_12800-_-20-226-103-_-Product) is cl 7 but a different voltage. What properties can I safely mix and what must I match?

Also, can you mix capacitys? I just noticed there are 4GB sticks on newegg, I would love to have another 8gb of ram, but im not sure what I can mix. For reference my mobo is: [GA-MA790FXT](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128377) with some slight overclocks.

Comment: *I have some of [broken link]*. This is why your question should be understandable without links, why "click here" or "this" are useless link text. With that external site down, your question becomes incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look for your mobo on the [**Crucial**](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=GA-MA790FXT-UD5P%20%28rev.%201.0%29) site or the [**Kingston**](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/modelsinfo.asp?SysID=54455&mfr=Gigabyte&model=GA&search_type=&root=us&LinkBack=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kingston.com&Sys=54455-Gigabyte-GA-MA790FXT-UD5P+Motherboard&distributor=0&submit1=Search) site, they will recommend upgrades that are compatible with it. It may be worthwhile speaking to them to find out if their mobo compatible memory is compatible with your current memory.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to match speeds and voltage exactly. Usually, the memory modules will run at the fastest speed that is supported by both the modules and the motherboard. Usually, mixing sizes is just fine. (I say usually, not always, because there is the occasional incompatibility, especially if you overclock. But that's rare.)

Your motherboard supports both ECC and non-ECC memory. Now that's something you generally cannot mix. That is, you can have ECC modules, and you can have non-ECC modules, but you can't have the two kinds together on the same motherboard.

I recommend buying memory from a vendor that guarantees compatibility with your motherboard (so if it turns out not to work, you get your money back with no hassle). I'm a satisfied [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/) customer, but don't let that distract you from checking out the competition.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of factors will depend on the actual motherboard and what it will actually support. Generally, you can get by with faster or slower (if the existing RAM is over-rated than the required specification) RAM of the same CAS and voltage. Some motherboards are strict on the mixing and grouping of RAM capacities too.